# Sums of infinite series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So the following are infinite series of positive term, satisfying $0\le a_n\le b_n$ .$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \,, \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$$ 
Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ is convergent. Can anyone help with concluding that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is also convergent.

I think i may have to use the squeeze principle, or perhaps the limits of the series (seeing as $b_n$ is convergent), but not sure how to go about this.

Comment: This is called the Direct Comparison Test

Comment: Hint: sequence of partial sums of the first series form is increasing and bounded (by sum of the second)

Comment: @Marcin_Łoś Cheers for that! Never really thought of partial sums of them.

Comment: @Hayden Just had a quick Google of that and its exactly what I was looking for. Don't know how I missed it flicking through notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us prove something analogous

> Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two sequences. $b_n$ and $a_n+b_n$ converges
>   then $a_n$ converges

Proof:
Note that: If $x_n$ and $y_n$ are two convergent sequences $x_n+y_n$ and $x_n-y_n$ converges.
In the previous statement take $x_n=a_n+b_n$ and $y_n=b_n$ and infer that $x_n-y_n=a_n+b_n-b_n=a_n$ converges.

To prove the series version of the theorem all you have to do is to consider the partial sum of the series and apply the same proof there.